# print image in a Gridview with print button c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

How can I print a gridview image from a `Gridview`?

```
| id |image      |print  |

| 1  |dessert.jpg| print |
```

I will like to click on print and be able to print the image. I am using .NET c#

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your print button you can write `JS` code like: `OnClientClick = window.print()` this will print your whole page.

If you want to print the image only then put that image into another page(programatically) and then write `script block` as `<script>window.print()</script>`, this will print the page, thanks.